# Is anyone using Monte Carlo Sim Analysis for Retirement Strategy?

Tags: retirement

I am trying to run Monte Carlo projections for retirement savings and goals. I know that there are a few good tools out there such as OnTrajectory.com and other websites. Is anyone out there performing Monte Carlo analysis on their finances? Any success?

Comment: Voting to close. This is more of a discussion prompt than an actual concrete question. This site is intended for getting answers to specific questions rather than form-style discussions. However, feel free to visit the chat area of the site where this is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I know the professional financial counselor I've used did so to sanity-check the recommentations they were giving me. "If it happens, it must be possible."

Answer (score 0):

I have my most of my retirement money with Wells Fargo. They did a Monte Carlo analysis to determine the probability that, given the amount I presently have put away and the amount I am putting away per year, whether I would have as much in retirement as I said I was shooting for. I got the impression that they do this routinely.